# Is saving current users id to db via controllers create action a bad choice in ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, rubygems

Is line number 3 in my create action considered bad practice?
Because a user has many photo_albums and an album needs to be linked to the right user I basically grab the id from current_user and store it in the user_id column of my photo_albums database table.

I'm sure this should be done from the model e.g before_save or before_create
I'm having trouble getting it to work. I created a method with an argument and tried to pass the current_user id into that method via the controller to the method written in my model then supplied that method name after before save but I either get wrong number of arguments error or undefined method.

Can some one explain how I can do this thanks very much.

```
  def create
    @photoalbum = PhotoAlbum.new(params[:photo_album])
    @photoalbum.user_id = current_user.id
    if @photoalbum.save
      flash[:notice] = "Successfully created gallery."
      redirect_to @photoalbum
    else
      render :action => 'new'
    end
  end
```

Kind regards

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with this,
but I'd be inclined to make it more specific.

You say a user `has_many :photo_album`

So instead we can say

```
  def create
    @photoalbum = current_user.photo_albums.build(params[:photo_album])
    if @photoalbum.save
      flash[:notice] = "Successfully created gallery."
      redirect_to @photoalbum
    else
      render :action => 'new'
    end
  end
```

This achieves the same thing,
but using the has_many makes it clearer our intent.